# building GTSAM with Boost from vcpkg

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, gtsam

I am trying to build GTSAM from source in windows.

I already have Boost for VCPKG and I can use it by adding these lines at the start of my cmake and then use find boost as follow:

```
File(TO_CMAKE_PATH $ENV{VCPKG_ROOT} VCPKG_ROOT)
message(STATUS ${VCPKG_ROOT})
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "${VCPKG_ROOT}/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake" CACHE STRING "")
set(VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET "x64-windows-static" CACHE STRING "")

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME ON)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS chrono date_time filesystem system thread timer REQUIRED)
```

so I am sure that vcpkg installation is correct.

When I try to use the same method in gtsam cmake file it fails to find boost. I added the above lines into gtsam cmake file and thought that it would find boost from vcpakg

why gtsam can not find boost?

Comment: Where have you added these lines? Variable `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` should be set **before** the `project()` call (this variable is usually set in the command line). `find_package` is normally called **after** the `project()` call.

Comment: @Tsyvarev The trick solved my problem, please raise it as answer and I will accept it.